# Moving A Method Inline - Resharper Possible

Tags: c#

I want to create an instance of `IEnumerable<T>` - I can do that by creating a method like

```
public IEnumerator<T> MakeEnumerator(){
    yield return 1;
}
```

But I need to pass this Enumerator to another class and so wanted to see whether I could create this inline with a delegate

Is that possible

EDIT: What I would like to remove is something like this:

```
new CustomClass(MakeEnumerator())
```

and replace with

```
new CustomClass(delegate...  ) // The method is now inline
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help, your generic code will look non-generic if you don't format your code blocks properly (and you have what, 120+ questions?).

Comment: Good point - Sorry for the typo - Thanks for updating

Comment: What do you mean "inline with a delegate", is your question how to pass something that can be enumerated over, that contains the single integer value 1, without having to create that method?

Comment: I don't get your intention. Can you give a better sample? You can use lambda expressions, too and if you want an enumerable you can use `Enumerable.Range` to create one, or just create a new list or array: `new CustomClass(() => new T[0]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delegates can not implement interfaces, so they can not be passed instead of IEnumerator interface. Only you can do is pass return value of delegate - i.e.:

```
var fuu = new CustomClass(Enumerable.Range( 1, 1 ))
```

.

Answer (score 3):

An iterator method cannot be made inline, for the simple reason that the code magic that is involved with anonymous methods doesn't support the code magic that is involved when creating iterator methods, or vice versa. An iterator method *must* be a separate methods, at least in current versions of C#.

However, if all you need is *something that can be enumerated over*, you can simply use an array.

So, to call method Test, with an enumerable collection:

```
Test(new[] { 1 });
```

If you need an `IEnumerator<T>` and not an `IEnumerable<T>`, simply call `GetEnumerator` before passing it to the method:

```
Test(new[] { 1 }.GetEnumerator());
```

Comment: Hi - Its not as east as creating an array with one item inside it - There is a bit of logic in the iterator and I was wondering if you could do like Java and have an anonymous method

Comment: That detail wasn't apparent in your question, but no, you can't. As I said, you can't combine an anonymous method with an iterator method.